# How to export media storage directory into an ACTION_VIEW intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a function attached to a button that looks like this:

```
public void viewSnappies(View z) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(Util.getOutputMediaFile().mediaStorageDir().getPath()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

In my Util Class, I have:

```
public final class Util {
    /**
     * Create a File for saving an image
     */
    // http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(Context context) {
        File mediaStorageDir = null;
        // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
        // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "snappiesticker");
        } else {
            ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
            mediaStorageDir = cw.getDir("imageDir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }


        // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
        // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) return null;
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;

        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

Right now the button is not working as I intend it to (error in the new Intent line). Its not resolving because I am putting the wrong thing into Uri.parse(). I want it to resolve to and use the mediaStorageDir defined in the getOutputMediaFile method given in the Util class.

How do I pass this variable correctly?

Comment: Then return the mediaStorageDir instead of mediaFile. So change the return type of your function.

Comment: but I need both. Another part of the app uses mediaFile. How would I format the return of both? and then be able to call them seperately?. Also instead of File as the type of output, what would I use?

Comment: Then add another function that returns mediaStorageDir. the type is File too.

Comment: No you don't need that as you get the mediaStorage dir with`Util.getOutputMediaFile().getParentFile().getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: What arguments would I pass to getOutputMediaFile()? Right now it gives me: getOutputMediaFile(Context) in Util cannot be applied to ()

Comment: A context of course. Try `this` or `MyActivity.this`.

Comment: I get with this, MyActivity.this, and getApplicationContext() : parse(java.lang.String) in Uri cannot be applied to java.io.File. Does this mean that the whole thing is returning a string? Should the pathname getParentFile returns be a string? or is the context still not right?

Comment: Instead of MyActivity you should use the name of your Activity. Now did you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66866/discussion-between-bigboy1337-and-greenapps).

Comment: I think the context is working. the error its giving seems to be because Uri.parse is expecting something other than what my method is returning (a string)

Comment: No your method is returning a `File` object. Remove the `Uri.parse`. Just use the string `Util.getOutputMediaFile(context).getAbsolutePath()`; For what do you want to use `mediaStorageDir` ?

Comment: I want it so that I can refer to it when when creating an image gallery for that particular folder/directory. However, sometimes this function will be called just to return the media directory and no file is being created. So I don't think getOutputMediaFile(context).getAbsolutePath() would work in that case, right?

Comment: You are asking for info you can easily find out yourself fiddling around with File and your function.